I get an error when adding a new language in the Loco translate plugin
I want to add a new language to the Loco Translate plugin and translate it, but I get the error "Error: Your site has encountered a serious problem. Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress issues. See console output for debugging information." When I look at the console, it gives the output "500 (Internal Server Error)". How can I solve it?



Have you tried contacting Loco Translate's support team yet? If not then give that a try, if anyone knows what's going on it will be them: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/loco-translate/

Try the following points:

Set WP_DEBUG to true in wp_config.php to check and fix if any error.
Increase the memory_limit to 512M and max_execution_time to 300
Deactivate all the plugins except Loco Translate and activate the default theme to check if the problem persists. If not, find which plugin or theme creates the problem.
If the above points are not helping contact the Loco Translate support for help.

